# Creating a synthetic census from census aggregates

Tags: python, r, optimization, data-science

This is my first post on stackoverflow as I was not too sure how to approach this problem.

I am currently working on the generation of a synthetic population but I wanted to revise my initial approach to the building of a synthetic census.

I have these datasets:

- age_area_aggregate: Has columns area, age, count
- sex_area_aggregate: Has columns area, sex, count
- ethnicity_area_aggregate: Has columns area, ethnicity, count
- arealess_aggregate: Has columns age, sex, ethnicity, count

The sum counts for these datasets slightly differ. I want to create a synthetic census where each row represents a person with area, age, sex and ethnicity features.

I originally performed joins but I want to use optimisation methods to improve the census quality. Does anyone have any advice / solutions that I could attempt to implement? Note: I am primarily using Python :)

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.